# AWS S3 File Copy - monitor when a file doesn't get moved into S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We move some of our log files from our instances into S3 to be consumed by a set of Client Metrics that we use to ensure that we are meeting client SLA's. Therefore, we need to be sure that the files are getting moved into their respective S3 buckets.

I've seen in the documentation where you can **create notifications based on when certain S3 events happen** such as file copy but I'm having trouble finding anything on the inverse of that - notification that gets triggered **when an event doesn't happen**.

In our scenario these log files are aggregated every 5 minutes and moved into their respective buckets so what we're looking to do is **if a file hasn't been detected as getting moved** into its bucket within the last 15 minutes, send off a notification to the respective notifying them of that to let them know that they need to go investigate.

We would like to do this without writing any Lambda functions or other custom utility code but using the native support and built in functionality to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you describe *without* writing custom code.

However, you could probably do it with a *little bit* of code. The flow would be:

- Configure an **Amazon S3 Event** to trigger an AWS Lambda function when an appropriate object *is* created
- The **AWS Lambda function** can send a **custom metric** to Amazon CloudWatch, such as `File Received = 1`
- Then, create an **CloudWatch Alarm** that triggers when the `SUM` of the metric for the previous 15 minutes is zero
- **Important:** Configure the Alarm's **Additional Configuration** to `Treat missing data as bad (beaching threshold)`
- Configure the alarm to send a notification to an **Amazon SNS topic**, then subscribe to that topic to receive notifications

The configuration to "treat missing data as bad" will cause the alarm to trigger even when no data is arriving.

The Lambda code would be as simple as:

```py
import boto3    

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Push a custom metric
    cloudwatch_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

    cloudwatch_client.put_metric_data(
        Namespace='log_arrivals',
        MetricData=[
            {
                'MetricName': 'logs_arrived',
                'Value': 1
            }
        ]

    )
```

Comment: Thank you John - I am going to add this post to our ticket of possible approaches for this challenge.